# Putting an image into an MKOverlayView in the MapKit in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit, mkoverlay

I want to make a mapkit overlay with a png, but i have no code for it and I cant find any tutorials on it. I am a novice coder, so lots of help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you need to do to get this going:

1. Create a custom [`MKOverlayView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass that actually draws your image.
2. Add an overlay (an object that implements the [`MKOverlay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol) to your `MKMapView`. Apple provides a number of overlay classes—[`MKCircle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html), [`MKPolygon`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolygon_class/Reference/Reference.html), etc.—one is likely to be suitable.
3. Implement the `mapView:viewForOverlay:` method in your `MKMapView`'s delegate to return an instance of your custom overlay view.

The section [Displaying Overlays on a Map](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15) in Apple's Location Awareness Programming Guide should help clarify all of these steps. As for drawing the image, have a look at [`CGContextDrawImage()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGContextDrawImage).

Comment: But i am not looking to have an overlay drawn on. I just want to paste a png image that I have over a part of the map and have it change depending on the zoom level. Does this all still apply?

Comment: If you want the image to stay in the same position on the map as the user pans around (say, over a particular city), then this is what you want. If you're going to position it yourself and just want it to change based on the zoom level, you could get away with just using key-value observing.

Comment: Could you help me with the code? I am a novice coder, and I dont really know where to start and what to write...

Comment: If you're having trouble getting started, I suggest you go (back) over the basics of Objective-C. Once you've got a good understanding of functions, inheritance, and protocols, the example code I linked to should be self-explanatory. Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html